# Using a Twig Extension

Tags: twig, template-engine

I am trying to use teh Twig i18n Extension.

As far as I can tell the file I need is here:

https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/I18n.php

Now I am not quite sure where to save this file

I have Twig in a folder called includes/lib (/includes/lib/Twig). I see a folder Extension under Twig. Do I save it here?

After I save it, do I need to do a "require_once" to the file or will Twig_Autoloader do the job for me?

I am not using Symfony2

Thanks
Craig

Comment: I just need a bump in the right direction.

Comment: I was afraid this wouldn't get an answer. The solution is probably way to easy and I don't get it. Still it would be nice if somebody could push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the complete answer that worked for me:

1. Copy the file in Twig-Verzeichnis (extract i18n.zip in Twig).
   For the I18n extension it would be Twig/Extensions/Extension/I18n.php
2. Eventually add other files requred by I18n. You will see what these are by the error messages that come. I had to add "Twig/Extensions/Node/Trans.php" and "Twig/Extensions/TokenParser/Trans.php".
3. In your config file add the following:

   ```
   // Set language to German
   putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE'); 
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); 
   // Specify location of translation tables
   bindtextdomain("project_de_DE", "./locale"); 
   // Choose domain 
   textdomain("projectl_de_DE");
   ```
4. Register the Twig Extension

   ```
   $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());
   ```
5. Create the directory locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES
6. Create the PO file (the easisest is to have a sample file to start from)
7. Open the file in a normal text editor (be sure to use utf-8 encoding) and start translating
8. Open the PO-Datei with PoEdit (www.poedit.net/)
9. Save to locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES (a MO-Datei will be created).
10. Add the translation to the appropriate places in the Twig-Template with

    ```
    {% trans 'Text in the original language' %}`
    ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register this extension with Twig:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());
```

If your installation is configured correctly, the autoloader should do the job of including the file. If not, you could include the file manually or make the installation with [composer](http://getcomposer.org).

Comment: Thanks that answered one part of my question. The other part is where to save the extension. After a bit of trial and error I found that the place to save the extension is in the extensions name. In this case Twig_Extension_Extension_I18n goes in the directory under the main Twig installation Extension/Extension/I18n. if other *stuff* is needed you will find that out in the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "proper" way to install these extensions without Composer is as follows:

1. Download a release from https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/releases
2. Copy the contents of the `lib/` directory somewhere to your project
3. include the file `.../Twig/Extensions/Autoloader.php`
4. Register autoloader: `Twig_Extensions_Autoloader::register();`
5. Continue as explained in the doc: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html